# Limit Scan Angle for LMS100

Tags: sicklms, laserscan

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am using the LMS1xx driver package for the LMS100 I have. The scan angle of the laser is 270 degrees. I want to reduce the scan angle of LMS100 to less than 180 degrees. Can the laser filter package do it? Or can it be done from the LMS1xx package itself?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/61538/limit-scan-angle-for-lms100/) by [arp](https://answers.ros.org/users/4543/arp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 172 on 2013-04-24

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This seems to be [a common question.](http://answers.ros.org/question/9667/limit-scan-angle-with-laser-filter/) :)

If you dont want to alter the laser driver, you can use the [laser_filters](http://ros.org/wiki/laser_filters) package as you already guessed.

Example of how to use this:

```
<launch>
  <node pkg="laser_filters" type="scan_to_scan_filter_chain"
      name="laser_filter">
    <rosparam command="load" file="laserscan_filter.yaml" />
  </node>
</launch>
```

With `laserscan_filter.yaml` containing:

```
scan_filter_chain:
- name: laser_cutoff
  type: laser_filters/LaserScanAngularBoundsFilter
  params:
    lower_angle: -1.60876090527
    upper_angle: 1.60876090527
```

---

Originally posted by [Ben_S](https://answers.ros.org/users/1072/ben_s/) with karma: 2510 on 2013-04-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kiran](https://answers.ros.org/users/24920/kiran/) on 2017-02-03**:
Hey, thanks for your answer. It is working. But I couldn't find this plugin in the [original](http://wiki.ros.org/laser_filters) documentation. Are there any other set of filters which are not mentioned?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello, i think that you are using driver here on [this page](http://www.ros.org/wiki/LMS1xx). This package uses libLMS1xx can be found [here](http://github.com/konradb3/libLMS1xx.git) , if you check LMS1xx.cpp and LMS1xx.h, you will see a config structure called scanCfg which has start angle and stop angle. You will see a function setScanCfg in LMS1xx.cpp that can be used to arrage start and stop angle. You can use these in LMS1xx_node.cpp in LMS1xx package. Hope this helps

---

Originally posted by [cagatay](https://answers.ros.org/users/2526/cagatay/) with karma: 1850 on 2013-04-25

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kalectro](https://answers.ros.org/users/3904/kalectro/) on 2013-07-10**:
did you get this to work? I tried just reading the config and sending it back to the device. The result was that it did not publish any scans at all